# Template parse errors (Angular CLI)

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou estudando Angular pela [doc](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5), porém quando cheguei em `Add HeroService.getHero()`, o aplicativo deu refresh e apresentou o seguinte erro:

> compiler.js:2547 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'hero' since it isn't a known property of 'app-hero-detail'.
>   1. If 'app-hero-detail' is an Angular component and it has 'hero' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-hero-detail' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>         
>       
>       ][hero]="selectedHero">
>
> "): ng:///AppModule/HeroDetailComponent.html@8:21
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
>       at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:19495)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25041)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25028)
>       at compiler.js:24971
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24971)
>       at compiler.js:24881
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:2538)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24880)

E eu não tô entendendo o que está acontecendo, tentei procurar por problemas parecidos, mas não consegui entender..

Os códigos eu disponibilizei no [git](https://github.com/LeTarzan/estudos-angular), já que é bastante coisa (4 componentes). Estou utilizando o Angular CLI.

Comment: pode adicionar o trecho que voce esta atuando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite, você tem alguns problemas em seu component, vou listar abaixo acredito que dessa forma pode corrigir!

1 - Em **hero-detail.component.ts** você tem propriedade **hero** porém ela não está com a diretiva **Input** do Angular, dessa forma não é possível receber/passar valor da forma que faz na linha 9 no **hero-detail.component.html**.

2 - Você está chamando o próprio component no **hero-detail.component.html** isso não faz sentido e foge da estrutura e definição do Angular

No seu caso o erro ocorre porquê o Angular não encontra o **app-hero-detail** definido na linha 9.